# Half of the 8GB RAM sometimes "missing", sometimes not

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

I've got 8GB installed on my ASUS Windows 7 laptop. Recently, there have been times when I've noticed the computer slowing down, and when I open the task manager I see only 4GB maximum on physical memory. The only solution so far has been booting computer repeatedly until I see 8GB again available, and the computer works accordingly well again. This problem has been bothering me every now and then, but during past few days the problem has escalated: The computer almost always starts with 4GB, opposed to that problem happening only occasionally like in the past. What to do? Is this perhaps sign of hardware breaking down?

Comment: I suspect that you have 4GB on the system board and a 4GB expansion, correct? I'd try re-seating the expansion.

Comment: Check what does BIOS reports - one 4G module or 2*2G modules. If first - clear contacts (on the sitting places - with great accuracy!!!), if second ... try to decrease memory speed.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with computer hardware, but I located two RAM cards inside the laptop: Both look the same and both are locked on similar stations, so I'm not sure which one would be the "expansion" one. Still, I removed and reattached both. The problem still persists, and given the amount of burned dust inside the laptop perhaps I can blame the faulty hardware on this one.

Comment: Re-seat them again but this time clean the contacts with a proper product.